# Python get direct attributes of a class

Tags: python

Say I have a class:

```
class Foo(Parent):

    a = 1
    b = 2

    def bar(self, x):
        pass
```

I want to list all its attributes, and I found `inspect`:

```
import inspect
inspect.getmembers(Foo)
```

but this gives all attributes of `Foo`, including those from `Parent`, but I only want `a`, `b`, `bar`

Comment: Why? It *does have* those attributes!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a way, but it's dirty and you would have to filter out things like `__module__` or `__doc__`:

```
Foo.__dict__
```

Answer (score 2):

But attributes defined on the parent *are* direct attributes of the child. That's how inheritance works, and is a fundamental principle. The object doesn't know or care where they were defined.

If you needed to work this out somehow, one approach might be to get the list of attributes of the parent, and subtract them from the list of the child's attributes. But you really shouldn't need this.